# getting index of string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm bashing my head over this one. I have tried using indexOf() and made my own function to iterate through the array and compare each term but I am always getting -1!

```
function checkindex(array,temp) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[i] + "   " + temp);
        if (array[i] == temp) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

array is an Object which is generated this way:

```
var array = (req.body.somestring).split(',');
```

When I output array and string this way:

```
console.log(array[i] + "   " + temp);
```

I get something like this:

```
["My variable","Something else"]     My variable
```

The spelling matches but its still -1. array.indexOf(temp) gives me the same results. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please make a complete example? Including input, actual output and expected output?

Comment: indexOf() doesn't work on arrays, just strings.

Comment: @PålThingbø Modern browsers/engines support indexOf on Arrays

Comment: I know, but it's not wise to use it. However the code above is corect, so my guess is it's something wrong with the array. What does console.log(array) show?

Comment: Hello, you are using  console.log(array[i] + "   " + temp);, but you area getting output as ["My variable","Something else"]     My variable, is the variable array is Array of Array I mean multidimensional array ?

Can you please output console.log(array)

Comment: @PålThingbø Why is it not wise to use it? It is IE9+

Comment: Because you get in trouble on older browsers and devices.

Comment: Your console.log line shows an array....Is that the actual output?

Comment: You can always use a polyfill for indexOf() as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Talking to epascarello point, if that is in fact your console output, you may be looping through an array of arrays rather than an array of strings. Try logging your array arguments before the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was actually more upstream... I stringified the data (JSON.stringify) prior to sending it so the string from `var array = (req.body.somestring).split(',');` included brackets and all. That why the output of console.log(array) looked like this:

```
["My variable","Something else"]
```

The elements in this situation are:

array[0] === ["My variable"

array[1] === "Something else"]

The solution was instead of split was use JSON.parse. The output of console.log(array) after that was:

```
My variable,Something else
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```js
var array = ["My variable","Something else"];
var lookup = "My variable";
var index = array.indexOf(lookup);
alert(index);
```

There is a nice polyfill for older browsers that can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: yes, we all know that `indexOf` exists and works. What do you think the OP's problem was?